# Conditional expectation of integrals random variable

Tags: probability, conditional-probability

I have a question regarding the conditional expectation of two integrals of random variables
Here are my hypothesis

Let $W_t$ be a Brownian motion.
$\Gamma_t$, $\mu_t$ et $\sigma_t$ three deterministic parameters such as:

$\lambda_t = \Gamma_t\exp(X_t)$

$dX_t=-\mu_tdt+\sigma_tdW_t$

$X_0$

$T_0, T_1 \in [0,T]$

I would like to calculate: $\mathbb{E}\Bigr(\exp \bigr(-\int_{0}^{T_1}{\lambda_sds\bigr)}\Bigr)$

Conditionning the above by $X_{T_0}$ I have:

$\mathbb{E}\Bigr(\exp(-\int_{0}^{T_1}{\lambda_sds}\bigr)\Bigr)=\mathbb{E}\Bigr(\mathbb{E}\bigr(\exp(-\int_{0}^{T_1}{\lambda_sds)}|X_{T_0}\bigr)\Bigr).$

But

\begin{align*}
\mathbb{E}\biggr(\exp\Bigr(-\int_{0}^{T_1}{\lambda_sds\Bigr)}|X_{T_0}\biggr)&=\mathbb{E}\biggr(\exp\Bigr(-\int_{0}^{T_0}{\lambda_sds\Bigr)}\exp\Bigr(-\int_{T_0}^{T_1}{\lambda_sds\Bigr)}|X_{T_0}\biggr) \\
&=\mathbb{E}\biggr(\exp\Bigr(-\int_{0}^{T_0}{\Gamma_s\exp(X_s)ds\Bigr)}\exp\Bigr(-\int_{T_0}^{T_1}{\Gamma_s\exp(X_s)ds\Bigr)}|X_{T_0}\biggr)
\end{align*}

My question is the following: conditioning to $X_{T_0}$, do we have:

$\exp\Bigr(-\int_{0}^{T_0}{\Gamma_s\exp(X_s)ds}\Bigr)$ and $\exp\Bigr(-\int_{T_0}^{T_1}{\Gamma_s\exp(X_s)ds}\Bigr)$ **independent** ?

In other words can I write:

\begin{align*}
\mathbb{E}\biggr(\exp\Bigr(-\int_{0}^{T_0}{\Gamma_s\exp(X_s)ds\Bigr)}\exp\Bigr(-\int_{T_0}^{T_1}{\Gamma_s\exp(X_s)ds\Bigr)}|X_{T_0}\biggr)
\\
&=\mathbb{E}\biggr(\exp\Bigr(-\int_{0}^{T_0}{\Gamma_s\exp(X_s)ds\Bigr)}|X_{T_0}\biggr).\mathbb{E}\biggr(\exp\Bigr(-\int_{T_0}^{T_1}{\Gamma_s\exp(X_s)ds\Bigr)}|X_{T_0}\biggr)
\end{align*}

?

Many thanks for your help.

Comment: Instead of conditioning on $X_{T_0}$, would it work if you condition on $\mathcal{F}_{T_0}$ instead? Here $\mathcal{F}_t = \sigma(X_s:0\leq s\leq t)$ for deterministic $t$, and $\mathcal{F}_\tau = \{A \in \mathcal{F}_{T}: A\cap \{\tau \leq t\} \in \mathcal{F}_t \text{ for all } t\}$ for all stopping times $\tau$. Otherwise this becomes a little complicated because you are not working with adapted processes.

edit: fixed a definition

Comment: Thanks for your response. Unfortunately i don't see what difference would it make if I do so :-(

Comment: $\exp\left(-\int_0^{T_0} \lambda_s\,ds\right)$ is not $X_{T_0}$-measurable, but it is $\mathcal{F}_{T_0}$-measurable. If you change the filtration in the problem, then you can apply a standard property of conditional expectations. Namely, whenever a random variable $X$ is $\mathcal{F}$-measurable and $\mathcal{F} \subseteq \sigma(X,Y)$,

$$\mathbb{E}[XY|\mathcal{F}] = X\mathbb{E}[Y|\mathcal{F}].$$